# Making an unedittable line in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, readonly

I already looked through the solution to a similar problem here

[How can you mark a portion of a text widget as readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180130/how-can-you-mark-a-portion-of-a-text-widget-as-readonly?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but i have tried to make it a little dynamic. Scenario is that a line marked `'readonly'` can be changed later in the program based on few condition.
This is my code below and it is calling the `READONLY` Class written by Bryan Oakley.

```
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        global text
        text = ReadonlyText(self)
        sb = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=text.yview)
        text.configure(state=DISABLED)
        text.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
        sb.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
    count = 1.0
    with open('chem_data2.txt') as f:

        for line in f:
            if count == 5.0:
                text.insert(str(count), line,'readonly')
            else:
                text.insert(str(count), line, 'readonly')
            count = count + 1.0

    f.close()
    text.bind('<Key>', self.keyrelease)

    pos = text.index('end')
    text.tag_configure("readonly", foreground="grey")



def keyrelease(self,event):
    text.configure(state=NORMAL)
    index = text.index(INSERT)
    pos = int(float(index))
    let = str(float(pos))
    word = text.get(str(float(pos)), str(pos) + '.end')
    print pos
    #pos = text.index('end')
    if float(pos) == 5.0:
        print 'i got here'
        #text.insert(str(5.0), 'line', 'read')
```

The above code takes a file as an input and marks each line of the file `'readonly'` at the initial stage but if the user cursor is at the 5th line the line should change to edittable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the "readonly" tag from the range of text. You will need to save a reference to the text widget:

```
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.text = ReadonlyText(...)

    def keyrelease(self,event):
        if some_condition:
            # make line 5 not readonly
            self.text.tag_remove("readonly", "5.0", "5.0 lineend")
```

---

Note: this code is wrong:

```
pos = int(float(index))
```

Text indices are *not* floating point numbers, they are two integers separated by a period. If you treat them as floating point numbers and try to compare them, you will get unexpected results. For example, as floating point numbers `5.2` is greater than `5.10`, but the text index `5.10` is *after* `5.2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the additional comment, kind of new to tkinter. I tried the tag_remove and i can delete the text in the line but cannot insert new text. So i went further by trying tag_delete, then voila, i can delete and insert. but the only drawback here is that all lines are also activated.

Comment: To insert you have to make sure that the index you are inserting at doesn't have that tag. The algorithm is pretty simple: if you try to insert or delete text, and the index you give it is inside a range that has the readonly tag, it won't allow it.