# Tkinter unmodifiable/modifiable Text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget, disable

I want to create a text widget, in order to write some credentials.
How can I insert a text that I can't modify, but still be able to write in the `Text` widget?

```
text = Text(root, wrap=NONE,
            xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
            yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

text.insert(INSERT, "Name: ")
text.configure(state='disabled')
```

I tried like this and it is ok, because I can't modify the text "Name: ", but the problem is that I can't write anymore in the `Text` widget.

Comment: Did you mean to have your text control positioned to the right of a Label with ‘Name:’ in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some text and then disable the text box to not be modified then you should set the state first to `normal`, insert the text then set it back to `disabled`.
Like this:

```
    text.configure(state='normal')
    text.delete('1.0', 'end')
    text.insert('1.0', "Name: ")
    text.configure(state='disabled')
```

This will clear the text box first, if you don't want that, just remove the second line. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180130/11024053) for how to disable just the first part of the text widget.

Comment: The user can't write in Text widget after i run the code. The whole widget gets disabled, not only the text ‘Name:’. I want so that the user can't delete/modify the text 'Name:',  that i insert for him, but i want him to be able to write in the widget.

Comment: @GheorgheGh Yes, check the link it solves the same problem.