# How do I make unclearable text in Tkinter's Text Field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Writing my Second tkinter project, I faced a problem.

The problem is: I need to make some unclearable text in the field(like you can't clear it with backspace). Is there any way to do it?

P. S. Don't suggest using Labels, I need unclearable text for TextField

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have a "Text Field". Are you referring to a `Text` widget, or an `Entry` widget? Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180132/7432

Comment: I mean ScrolledText/Text

Comment: i think what your looking for is called a placeholder and tkinter does not have a placeholder by default, tho u could make them, like @BryanOakley showed

Comment: @CoolCloud: I don't think they are asking about a placeholder. I think they just want a region of text that can't be deleted. Placeholder text is "deleted" (goes away) when you click in an entry field.

Comment: @BryanOakley exactly, i mean a region of text that can't be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can create a textbox and make its state disabled.

`tb1 = Text(root, state = "disabled")`

Now you won't be able to edit the text inside the textbox.

Comment: yeah, but i need the rest of the text field working

Comment: oh, so you want it such that the user can add text in it but not erase your text?