# How do I keep a specific lines and index of text disabled and not edited on tkinter textbox widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm creating a Terminal for a OS i'm currently working on. The design is based on Windows Command Prompt. But I have a few problems with the Default Text as when I press backspace, it gets locked on that place because the current position of the index is lower than the one which was set to. As well as, If I decided to use Control+A it selects all the text and can be deleted as well.

Here's the Code for my terminal:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

current_host = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
current_directory = (os.getcwd()+'> ')

def handle_key(event):
    cursor_pos = text_box.index("insert")
    if cursor_pos <= "1.0":
        return "break"

    elif cursor_pos < f"4.{len(current_directory)}":
        return "break"

    elif cursor_pos == f"4.{len(current_directory)}":
        return

    
main = Tk()
main.geometry('900x500')
main.title('Koshi Terminal')
main.config(bg='#e3afd3')

# Text Box for Terminal
text_box = Text(main, font=('Consolas', 11), bg='#fff', fg='#000', bd=0, selectbackground='#fff', selectforeground='#000', insertwidth=10)
text_box.pack(anchor=W, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

# Initial Text
initial_text = "Koshi's Test Terminal Version 1.0 \n\n"
text_box.insert('insert', initial_text)
text_box.insert('insert', current_directory)

# Bind key press event
text_box.bind("<Key>", handle_key)

main.mainloop()


#Current Bugs Encountered:
#   - if You used the Control+A function to select all text, and press delete or backspace, the default text gets deleted as well and not maintained.
#   - if you backspace until reached the '>' part, you cannot edit the input area because of the cursor's point.
```

The 'handle_key' Function is responsible for detecting the cursor's position and 'break' the input when it gets lower. I tried using the '>=' operator but just makes it worse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11180130/7432